# When i use jarsigner for sign my apk error message apeared

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, jarsigner

when i use jarsigner for sign my apk .i use `it` command

```
 C:\>jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks android-release-unsigned.apk my-alias 

Enter Passphrase for keystore:
```

but it say :

```
jarsigner: unable to open jar file: android-release-unsigned.apk .the name is correct
```

what i am doing bad ?the name of apk is the correct and of jks too

Comment: How did you do that.Can you comment that solution.Then if anyone get an issue same like yours they can get your answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

make sure password keystore same with ur type at Enter Passphrase for keystore:

password keystore u create before